# What does "a continuation from the feminine to the masculine line" mean in the context below?

Tags: dreams, freud

I am currently reading, *The Interpretation of Dreams* by *Sigmund Freud,* I  didn't understand the term below. What does it mean?

> Of many dreams it can be ascertained by a careful interpretation that they are even to be taken bisexually, inasmuch as they result in an irrefutable secondary interpretation in which they realize homosexual feelings — that is, feelings that are common to the normal sexual activity of the dreaming person. But that all dreams are to be interpreted bisexually, seems to me to be a generalization as indemonstrable
> as it is improbable, which I should not like to support. Above all I should not know how to dispose of the apparent fact that there are many dreams satisfying other than — in the widest sense — erotic needs, as dreams of hunger, thirst, convenience, &c. Likewise the similar assertions “that behind every dream one finds the death sentence” (Stekel), and that every dream shows **“a continuation from the feminine to the masculine line”** (Adler), seem to me to proceed far beyond what is admissible in the interpretation of dreams.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  Just noting that Freud's works are considered [pseudoscience and out of date](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2242/7001), so this question only has relevance for historical purposes.

Comment: I have to agree with @ArnonWeinberg in the sense that there is no scientific consensus on the accuracy of dream interpretation. As for the line you mention, it is referring to something Alfred Adler said, which I am unfamiliar with. The link provided by Arnon has an answer written by me which does cover dream interpretation  which you may find helpful.

Comment: I think it could be referring to Adler's writings on Gender Guiding Lines and Role Models which are definitely not in keeping with now generally accepted knowledge on gender and "what it means to be a man or woman" https://www.adlerpedia.org/concepts/56